# In JavaScript, isn't Object Literal Notation just another name for a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, object, literals, notation

Isn't a JavaScript "Object" just a dictionary? Why is there a fancy name for Object Literal Notation? And for JavaScript Object Literal Notation, you can only refer to the object's property's value with `Object.property` and not `Object[property]` (as you would do in Python)?

Comment: `Object[property]` is valid in Javascript.

Comment: If `property` is strictly numeric or includes spaces or other characters or is the result of an expression, you _must_ use `Object[property]`

Comment: Everything in JS is a dictionary, but i guess i always thought of object-literal notation as a way to define objects in a more readable way that feels like classes.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: A Python dict doesn't have to just contain scalars. The values can be anything, including functions and `"I am z"`s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascript's "Object Literal Notation" is simply the syntax that javascript accepts for a statically declared data structure.  While a javascript object can be used similarly to what is called a dictionary in other languages, "Object Literal Notation" is just a static declaration syntax.  It would typically look something like this:

```
var myObject = {
    name: "Peter Foti",
    'course': 'JavaScript',
    grade: 'A',
    level: 3
};
```

The term "Object Literal Notation" does not refer to all possible ways that you can address an object with javscript code.  You don't use either the `Object.property` or `Object[property]` syntax to define a property in a static object declaration except as the value part of a declaration where the Object is some other object.

[This article](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php) has a good reference on the Object Literal syntax under the heading *Basic Syntax*.